# future.delay in Flutter how long can it be does it depend on device watch?

Tags: flutter, function, dart, timer, delay

Can it be used for daily, weekly or monthly subscription? Can it be manipulated by users? I mean does it effect when changing user device's time zone or location.

My problem
user can add a post a day and I want set timer 24h till he can add post again

what I am thinking

ontap:

addpost();

Future.delayed(Duration(hours: 24));

setstate ()=> reset post limit

Comment: 1. `Future.delay` schedules a `Future` during the lifetime of your application.  It's not going to exist once your application terminates. 2. Using `Future.delay` for your purpose would be inappropriate anyway.  The normal way to do such a thing is to compute and store a timestamp when the user is allowed to perform the action again.  If you want to prevent the user from manipulating their local time on their device, then you would need to retrieve the current time from some trusted server.